# git: no mergetool available

Tags: git, mergetool

I intend to set winmerge as my merge tool together with GitHubDesktop. Before I implement https://gist.github.com/shawndumas/6158524, out of curiosity, I tried to run git mergetool -- tool-help. I get "The following tools are valid, but not currently available." Referring to the git documentation (https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool), I understand that, at this point, no conflict resolution will happen if any after the merge. Am I correct?

Thanks

Comment: I think that the selected answer (Matt Clark) is not to your question.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but you asked about if git is able to solve automatically conflicts even in the case you didn't configure a mergetool.

MergeTool is not responsible of the automatic resolution of conflicts... in fact this is the part that git deals with internally.

When you call `git merge`,  the automatic solution effort is accomplished.
If it does not solve all conflicts, git asks for a user manual intervention that can be done by means of a simple editor or of a mergetool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure git to look for the proper tool:

```
git config --global merge.tool winmerge
```

If the application can not be automagically located, you might need to specify the exact path to the binary

```
git config --global mergetool.winmerge.path C:/Program\ Files/Winmerge/path/to/binary.exe
```

Then try again.

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify my question. I am just curious to what is happening **before** I even try to install and configure winmerge. My understanding is that, now,  as there is not mergetool available, there will be no conflict resolution. So GitHubDesktop will announce a conflict but will make no attempt to resolve it.

Comment: Correct, it would be as if you closed the merge tool without taking any actions. The files will still have the `<<< === >>>` git markers where conflicts were detected.

Answer (score 1):

about your question that received in my opinion no (correct) answer:

> Referring to the git documentation (https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool), I understand that, at this point, no conflict resolution will happen if any after the merge. Am I correct?

git does not try to resolve automatically conflict using mergetools, these tools are just to solve manually (but with a GUI) the ones that `git` was not able to solve.

So even if you didn't configure winmerge, when you execute   `git merge` , git tries to resolve conflicts with its internal conflict resolution algorithms.
If the differences between the versions to merge are in different files or in different hunks of a same file, **git solve them**, otherwise git marks the conflict zones with <<< === >>>.

A mergetool just presents you a way to tell how to solve these remaining conflicts.

Comment: I would not say that the previous answer was incorrect, but yours is definitely very clear and precise. Thanks for that.

Comment: happy that it helped you... 
if you appreciated it, when you will have more reputation (I think that now you cannot do that) remember of this and come back to  click on the up arrow of my answer to give me one point ;-)